# Prevent bash array name from being changed to _= (underscore equals)?

Tags: bash, scope

```
# script.sh
get_config() {
  declare -a liquibase_commands=( dropAll update )
  declare -p | grep liquibase
}

main() {
  get_config
  declare -p | grep liquibase
}

main "$@"
```

---

```
$ bash script.sh
declare -a liquibase_commands='([0]="dropAll" [1]="update")'
declare -- _="liquibase_commands: [  ]"
```

I was expecting `liquibase_commands` to be set and available in `main` after calling `get_config`; however, I am seeing `declare -- _=`.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Available where?

Comment: `declare` within a function is implicitly local (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare)). To fix it, either use `-g` (global) as in `declare -ag`, or drop `declare -a` altogether as it's not required to create an array.

Comment: Also, instead of `declare -p | grep liquibase`, you can use `declare -p liquibase_commands` directly.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I can't find documentation on `declare -g` on the web. Only `help -m declare`. Do you know if this exists on the web somewhere?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'll accept your `-ag` comment as the answer if you post it.

Comment: @EricFrancis it's in the bash manual https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins `The -g option forces variables to be created or modified at the global scope, even when declare is executed in a shell function. It is ignored in all other cases.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`declare`, when used in a function, implies `local`, i.e., the declared variable isn't visible outside of the function.

To fix that, you can explicitly declare the array as global using the `-g` flag:

```
declare -ag liquibase_commands=( dropAll update )
```

This was introduced in Bash 4.2. For older versions of Bash, you can just drop `declare` altogether, as Bash figures out on its own that `liquibase_commands` is an array:

```
liquibase_commands=( dropAll update )
```

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare) says this about the scope of variables declared with `declare`:

> The `-g` option forces variables to be created or modified at the global scope, even when `declare` is executed in a shell function. It is ignored in all other cases.
>
> [...]
>
> When used in a function, `declare` makes each *name* local, as with the `local` command, unless the `-g` option is used.

Comment: `help declare` and the man page are both pretty explicit: "When used in a function, 'declare' makes NAMEs local, as with the 'local'
    command." (The wording varies slightly depending on which version of `bash` you are using.)

Comment: @chepner Oh, right! I see it in my `help` for Bash 4.3. Checking the manual now.